# JBoss EAP 6.0 in Eclipse (Kepler): How do you run a custom script at startup?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I have a project that runs in JBoss EAP 6.0.  However, it currently requires that a custom script (.bat) is run at startup.

This is possible in IntelliJ.  When settings up a Run/Debug Configuration, a tab is provided titled "Startup/Connection" in which a "Startup script" can be targeted.

Eclipse is my preferred IDE but it does not appear to have this option.  I have tried several things without any results.

Answer (score 0):

I know in Eclipse, you can select which JBoss config file you choose to run on the Server view after you create a new Server config.

Alternatively, you can modify JBoss running scipt which will call your custom script.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Eclipse Marketplace and try installing Jboss Tools and you should be able to start server and whole lot of other options.

Go to Help> Eclipse Marketplace and search "Jboss tools" and install the appropriate for your version of eclipse.